# Does threading interfere the normal working behaviour of program?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, nsoperation

I have a view controller that is sub class of UIViewController which has table view into it and each rows in table view is linked to distinct xml url. I made a parser class that is sub class of NSOperation and implemented methods to parse the XML file on selection of each row as,

```
   -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(pushView) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(parseOperation:) withObject:indexPath];
}

-(void)pushView{
detailView = [[viewDetailsController alloc] initWithNibName:@"viewDetailsController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailView animated:YES]; 
}

 -(void)parseOperation:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
self.queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
parserClass *parser = [[parserClass alloc] initWithParseUrl:[[self.arrayOfUrls objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]delegate:self];
[queue addOperation:parser];
[parser release];
[pool release];
}
```

Parser works great but in its custom delegate method I have called to push view controller on the top of the navigation controller stack, the view controller initializes correctly but the new view controller is not pushed into the screen.
I dont have any idea about why this is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All UI calls must be made from the main thread, which may include allocating/initializing UI classes. It sounds like you are breaking that rule in your custom delegate method.

Comment: So, is it wrong to have called the parser in the background thread. I think I have done the same called the view pusher on the main thread while parser in the background thread.

Comment: @Core: The parser should probably run on the background thread, so it doesn't lock up your user interface while it parses. But you must use `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:` from its delegate methods to invoke a selector on the main thread to update the user interface.

Answer (score 0):

You should work with UI only from the main thread.
So in your delegate method you have to add something like

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(showImage:) withObject:aImage waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Or you can call a method of tableView directly:

```
[tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```